# hsqldb-2.3-2 does not work with Spring-4.2.4.RELEASE

Tags: xml, maven, spring-mvc, hsqldb, logback

I follow an online guide to use springmvc with java based configuration. However, while they made it run, I encounter a problem.

My practice is to load a web page named index.jsp. It would work if I did not add hsqldb into pom.xml

Specificall, If I did not declare hsqldb in pom.xml (of course I also dismiss code related to HSQL), then my page can be loaded.

However, when I need to add hsqldb package into pom.xml to use it, the page can not be loaded with the http 404 error (resources is not available)

There is nothing to do with the java code because the problem is still there after I remove all the code realted to hsql calls. I found that the presence of hsql package makes the page unable to be loaded. The Spring server is still up and running without any warning or error but the logback does not show anything as before when hsql wasn't be added.

Please help me out of this problem.

[image: Project structure]

Comment: Please add link to the online howto you've followed

Comment: Thanks! Here is the link on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FGK-9ayBQ3Q   In the link, everything works just fine but something went wrong everytime I added hsqldb in pom.xml. In the previous video taught how to create index.jsp and load it. In this video, the application is improved to work with database.